# Tests POST request with pytest

Tags: python, http, post, pytest

I'm in the middle of writing a test in pytest for my python app (flask).
The AddMessage function receives user input, generates a message, and stores it in the database.

```
@app.route('/AddMessage',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def AddMessage():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       data = request.form
       user_id = data['user_id']
       content = data['content']
       paticipants = [data['participant1'],data['participant2'],data['participant3']]
       m = Message(user_id=user_id,content=content,participants=paticipants)
       db.session.add(m)
       db.session.commit()
       return 'Your message has been successfully saved'
```

How can I test it? After all, during the test I can't get input, can I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this code:

```py
def test_addMessage(self):
        with self.app() as client, self.app_context():
            data = {
                "user_id": "1", 
                "content": "a content", 
                "participant1":"participant1",
                "participant2":"participant2",
                "participant3":"participants"
            }

            response = client.post(
                "/AddMessage",
                data=json.dumps(data),
                headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            )
            self.assertEqual(201, response.status_code)
            self.assertEqual('Your message has been successfully saved', response.data)
```

Another way more simple is to make a request:

```
import requests
import json
data = {
         "user_id": "1", 
         "content": "a content", 
         "participant1":"participant1",
         "participant2":"participant2",
         "participant3":"participants"
       }
response = requests.post("/AddMessage", json=json.dumps(data))
json_response = response.json()
print(json_response)
```

For more details, read the requests [documentation](https://realpython.com/python-requests/)

Comment: I get this message:
fixture 'self' not found.
I need to import something for it to work, right?
thanks!!

Comment: No, you must create a class and put the method in them.